# How to access to the same named column between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

```
$askforuser=$db->query("SELECT u.*,ud.* FROM users u INNER JOIN user_detail ud ON ud.userid=u.id"); 
$askforuser1 = $askforuser->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

users and user_details tables have 'created_at' column.

When i go like:

```
    foreach ($askforuser1 as $udet) {
extract($udet);
echo $created_at;
}
```

I see nothing on the screen but if i

```
foreach ($askforuser1 as $udet) {
    extract($udet);
    echo $userid; // user_detail table output.
    echo $id; // users table output;
    }
```

So, how can i get the users' created_at or user_detail's created_at?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the Sql query

```
SELECT u.*,ud.*, u.created_at as `user_created_at`,  ud.created_at as `user_details_created_at` FROM users u INNER JOIN user_detail ud ON ud.userid=u.id
```

Then get it in PHP after the extract as

```
   $user_created_at // user table
   $user_details_created_at // user_details table
```

Comment: My pleasure, if you can give me a +1 I will appreciate it ;)